# "На это есть две основные причины". Можно ли поставить точку после "причины"?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Собственно сам текст:

"Здесь есть две основные причины. Вы не выбрали вашу специализацию, и поэтому клиенты вам не доверяют. Они не верят методам и не знают о вашем бренде".

P. S.: нужны ли слова "во-первых", "во-вторых"?

Comment: Точку поставить можно, ибо ясно и так, что далее будут излагаться эти две причины. А вот добавить какое-то слово для разграничения причин придется. Например "Либо они не верят..."


Вообще, точка мой любимый знак препинания))). Если сомневаешься, какой знак препинания ставить - ставь точку и начинай следующее предложение, а читатель сам разберется как правильно связать эти предложения чтобы они приобрели верный смысл.

Answer (score 1):

Постановка точки здесь вполне возможна, это три самостоятельных предложения. Однако у слушателя/читателя может возникнуть затруднение по поводу того, где вы закончите излагать первую причину и приступите ко второй. На письме можно оформить причины в виде списка, или же добавить ясное указание на переход ко второй причине:

> Сколько я могу понять, тут были **две причины**. Ей было тяжело видеть
>   человека, которому она была слишком много обязана, по ее мнению. Она
>   ошибалась в этом, она не была нисколько обязана мне, потому что я
>   действовал гораздо больше для себя, нежели для нее. Но ей
>   представлялось иначе, и она чувствовала чрезвычайно сильную
>   признательность ко мне. Это чувство тяжелое. В нем есть приятная
>   сторона, но она имеет верх только тогда, когда чувство не слишком
>   сильно. Когда оно сильно, оно действительно. 
>   **Другая причина**, ― это опять несколько щекотливое объяснение...(Чернышевский)
>
> Здесь **две причины**. **Первая** ― развитие и механизация промышленных
>   производств, и, как следствие этого, увеличение спроса на смазочные
>   материалы. **Вторая** ― специфические особенности бакинской нефти,
>   содержащей большое количество (около 20%) высококипящих углеводородов.
>   (О. Юркевич)